# vb.net datetimepicker default date

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I am having an issue with a datetimepicker field and am wondering if what I want to accomplish can be done or not.    I have a datetime field in my 'Customer' table called 'LastVisit'.   When the Customer is created, the LastVisit field is empty or null.

When the user enters the edit screen for a customer, if they don't change the LastVisit field and then save the record, it stays empty - - which is what I want it to do.   Here is the problem though, if I set the datetimepicker.value in the screen design it stays that date, so eventually the users will need to click forward many months to get to the current month.   If I set the datetimepicker.value = today in the Form_load event, then it sets the value and it gets written to the Customer record even if the user does not go into that field.

What I would like to do is have the default date be 'today', but still have it so the LastVisit field will remain empty unless the user sets it.   Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You should have some code updating the table LastVisit, tell the program not to update the table unless the user picks a new date. You could do this by setting a boolean.
e.g On your form load, UserPicks as Boolean = False then say on an event such as MouseDown on the date-time picker you can set UserPicks to True.
I've put this as a comment as it seems quite simple? or is there a reason this cannot be done?

Comment: I tried setting the datetimepicker.value with that event, but you have to click on it twice.   I am using tableadapters, so I am not sure where I would set the date back to Null and not sure it would let me do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.   I had set a date as the value in the Properties of the datetimepicker field when I first created the form.   I was looking for other ideas and found that I could right click on the 'value' property and reset it to the default, which is the current time.  Now it behaves like I want.